# How to execute logic only if an element is visible

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I don't know if this is possible but I want to branch my code and only perform an action on an element if it exists in the DOM,  otherwise I want the test to continue as normal, something like this:

```
def reset_filters()
  clear_filters() if find(:filter_icon_button).exists?
end
```

Whenever I do this, the tests always fails because it can't find the selector, which is the thing I'm trying to test.

How can I make this work?

Comment: We don't care if you're new to a language. We only care that you've researched the problem and put in effort to solve the problem, then asked a concise and well-asked question. "[ask]", "[mcve]" and their linked pages, and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)" are useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one of the `has_xxx?` methods which return a boolean result rather than raising if it can't find - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_selector%3F-instance_method

```
def reset_filters()
  clear_filters() if page.has_selector?(:filter_icon_button)
end
```

Note: This will wait up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds for a matching element to be visible on the page (and then return false if it never does). If you just want it to immediately decide without the possible waiting you can do

```
page.has_selector?(:filter_icon_button, wait: 0) # or wait: false
```